# XML -> Dataset - temp-table - recid field issue

Tags: xml, dataset

A follow up from a question from March.

Summary (will post details below): 10.1c version (old) Reading in XML to Dataset with multiple temp-tables (multi table relations) but the "parentid" fields in the temp-table are not populated. Only have ? (null) so I can't properly join the parent / child relation on "parentid".

Main question: How do I get the parentid field to populate properly? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I will do my best to paste all relevant code below:

'''

```
define temp-table ga_export NO-UNDO 
   FIELD parentid AS RECID 
. 

define temp-table ga_journal  
   field parentid as recid      
   field ga_journal_id as int
   field ga_journal_type_ind as character
   field ga_unapplied_cash_ind as logical
   field ga_named_user as character
   field ga_action as character
   field ga_amount as decimal
   field ga_amount_allowed as decimal
   field ga_amount_over as decimal
   field ga_currency as character
   field ga_operation as character
   field ga_custno as character
   field ga_invno as character
   field ga_batchnum as int
.

 define temp-table ga_receipt
   field parentid as recid
   field ga_receiptnum as int
   field ga_checknum as int
   field ga_amount as decimal
.
  
 define temp-table ga_posting
   field parentid as recid
   field ga_gl_code as character
   field ga_gl_name as character
   field ga_gl_category as character
   field ga_artarget_desc as character
   field ga_artarget_id as character
   field ga_fr_unit as character /* level="Division" */ 
   field ga_fr_unit2 as character /* level="Sales Area" */
.

define temp-table ga_deposit
   field parentid as recid
   field ga_deposit_id as int
   field ga_date as date
   field ga_amount as decimal
   field ga_currency as character
.
            
define temp-table ga_bank
   field parentid as recid
   field ga_name as character
   field ga_micr_routing as int
   field ga_micr_account as int
.

DEFINE DATASET dsGAExport FOR ga_export, ga_journal, ga_receipt, ga_posting, ga_deposit, ga_bank
   DATA-RELATION drexju FOR ga_export, ga_journal RELATION-FIELDS (parentid, parentid)
   DATA-RELATION drjure FOR ga_journal, ga_receipt RELATION-FIELDS (parentid, parentid)
   DATA-RELATION drjupoe FOR ga_journal, ga_posting RELATION-FIELDS (parentid, parentid)
   DATA-RELATION drjude FOR ga_journal, ga_deposit RELATION-FIELDS (parentid, parentid)
   DATA-RELATION drdeba FOR ga_deposit, ga_bank RELATION-FIELDS (parentid, parentid)
.


lRetOK = DATASET dsGAExport:READ-XML(cSourceType, outFileName, cReadMode, cSchemaLocation,
        lOverrideDefaultMapping, cFieldTypeMapping, cVerifySchemaMode).
```

'''

Then when I try to display the parentid (recid) from each table it is just null. XML data is in the table as I would expect, except without parentid (recid) I can't seem to be able to join / display the data in a relationship fashion.

Again, any help is appreciated.

XML EXAMPLE CODE BELOW:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ga_export>
    <ga_journal>
        <ga_journal_id>29</ga_journal_id>
        <ga_journal_type_ind>C</ga_journal_type_ind>
        <ga_unapplied_cash_ind>false</ga_unapplied_cash_ind>
        <ga_named_user>GET</ga_named_user>
        <ga_action>C</ga_action>
        <ga_amount>52071.83</ga_amount>
        <ga_amount_allowed>0.00</ga_amount_allowed>
        <ga_amount_over>0.00</ga_amount_over>
        <ga_currency>USD</ga_currency>
        <ga_operation>TR_POST</ga_operation>
        <ga_custno>1006</ga_custno>
        <ga_invno>12093</ga_invno>
        <ga_batchnum>1001</ga_batchnum>
        <ga_receipt>
            <ga_receiptnum>1001</ga_receiptnum>
            <ga_checknum>1001</ga_checknum>
            <ga_amount>52071.83</ga_amount>
        </ga_receipt>
        <ga_posting>
            <ga_gl_code>2000</ga_gl_code>
            <ga_gl_name>TAR</ga_gl_name>
            <ga_gl_category>TRADE_RECEIVABLE</ga_gl_category>
            <ga_artarget_desc>DEFAULT</ga_artarget_desc>
            <ga_artarget_id>DEFAULT</ga_artarget_id>
            <ga_fr_unit level="Division">DIV01</ga_fr_unit>
            <ga_fr_unit level="Sales Area">Template</ga_fr_unit>
        </ga_posting>
        <ga_deposit>
            <ga_deposit_id>6</ga_deposit_id>
            <ga_date>2017-04-26</ga_date>
            <ga_amount>57871.83</ga_amount>
            <ga_currency>USD</ga_currency>
            <ga_bank>
                <ga_name>Bobs Bank</ga_name>
                <ga_micr_routing>987654321</ga_micr_routing>
                <ga_micr_account>123456789</ga_micr_account>
            </ga_bank>
        </ga_deposit>
        <ga_exportTimestamp>20170426163505</ga_exportTimestamp>
    </ga_journal>
</ga_export>
```

Comment: I think you should minimize your example in order to focus on the actual problem.

Comment: @ceving I understand I probably shared too much, but since I am not really sure WHERE my issue is coming from I shared a lot. I am VERY open to suggestions on what to narrow this down to. true issue is XML > Dataset / Temp tables - Don't know how to get relationship working. Assumed it was parentid not populating, but I could be way off.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.